# string splitting in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I have below mentioned 2 string as input.

```
Mon May 22 04:18:11 2017       call duration
```

and

```
call duration
```

I want to get `Mon May 22 04:18:11 2017` as an output.

How can I write regular expression to get this value using TCL?

Comment: Could you please precise what issue you are having? Share the code that does not work.

Comment: Could you at least explain what `call duration` string has to do with the question? Do you want to say you need to remove this substring (is it user-defined?) from a larger string?

Comment: Just checked: you do not need any regexps, see http://ideone.com/bfc56s

Comment: Do the old day of the week, month of the year, day, time regex. Like `(mon|tue|wed|...) (jan|feb|mar|..) \d\d? \d[\d:]+\d \d\d\d\d` That will get you out of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this: (tired, please pardon the crappy varnames)

```
proc prefix {big_str little_str} {
    # find the position of the first "little string" in the "big string"
    set index [string first $little_str $big_str]
    # get the substring that precedes that index
    return [string range $big_str 0 $index-1]
}
```

Testing (it even works when the little string is not found)

```
% prefix "Mon May 22 04:18:11 2017       call duration" "call duration" 
Mon May 22 04:18:11 2017       
% prefix "Mon May 22 04:18:11 2017       call duration" "XYZ" 
%
```